# Apple Watch for Multiple target

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I have multiple target in my App like QA,Release,Develop and i want to create watch app for all targets I have already added watch app for QA target and my question is How can i use same classes and storyboard for other targets e.g Release and Develop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Framework, in which you include all classes and files that you need to access from each target and then include the framework in your targets. [Embedding Frameworks in an app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543)

Answer (score 0):

I think a watch app target can only have one companion iOS application. Different `target` (QA, Release, Develop) means different `bundle ID`. Watch target `bundle ID` has to match companion app's `bundle ID` as its prefix.

For example, `com.xxx.yyy.watchkitapp` has to have an iOS companion with `com.xxx.yyy`. Therefore I think it's impossible.

However, if your code base for all targets are roughly the same you can have single target with multiple build `Configurations`.
[image]

Inside `Build Settings` for the single target, you can set different flags for `Preprocessor Macros`.
[image]

In code, you can do something like this to differentiate each build configuration.

```
#if QA
    // enable QA feature
#elseif RELESE
    // disable beta features
#else
    // enable everything
#endif
```